# ¿Como trataremos a los usuarios nuevos, primera pregunta?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

¿Estamos copiando el modelo actual de Stack Overflow para tratar a **los nuevos usuarios que todavía no entienden el formato**?. Es decir: votos en contra, bandera de cierre y comentarios explicativo. En ese orden.

Me parece que no va a funcionar bien para nosotros. La mayoría de los sitios sobre programación en español funcionan con un formato diferente al nuestro, el formato de hilo o thread.

*Si bien Stack Exchange deberá lograr que el publico se acerque y haga una pregunta, **lograr que se queden es trabajo nuestro**.*

Pienso que nosotros **deberíamos diferenciarnos** en la forma de darles la bienvenida.

Hay varias cosas que creo se pueden hacer para que se sientan bienvenidos en vez de rechazados. La intención de este post es que las discutamos. Y si, este tema es un tema de opinion, pero **la acción por defecto actual necesita ser revisada**.

Yo propongo estas guías básicas:

- **Hacer un comentario constructivo**: Lo esencial es que comprendan como funciona el formato y que entiendan la diferencia entre una pregunta que se puede contestar y una que no. Cada caso va a ser único, la paciencia y la amabilidad es lo mejor que tenemos, ademas del chat.
- **No votar en contra, como mucho que no supere -1**: Sí hacen una pregunta y reciben -3 en los primeros minutos (ayer [alguien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553/windows-10-versi%C3%B3n-home-o-pro) recibió -6), es de esperarse que se sientan rechazados. La persona que esta en el otro monitor siente erróneamente que lo están agrediendo y esto los alejara, recuerda que *en otros sitios los reciben con amabilidad*, les piden aclaraciones y no sienten que los castigan.

¿Qué piensan?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo contigo, comentar constructivamente

Comment: Estoy parcialmente de acuerdo. Si bien tiene que haber alguna manera de hacerlos sentir bienvenidos, los votos negativos y los cierres son indispensables para mantener la calidad del sitio.

Comment: Stack Overflow es un site de preguntas y respuestas, no un *foro*.

Comment: @brasofilo claro, pero ellos aun no lo saben. son usuarios nuevos.

Comment: Bueno, es el riesgo que tiene llegar a un site nuevo y salir preguntando sin ni siquiera mirar cuales son las reglas basicas, y hay situaciones que es directamente ofensivo. En general, hago comentarios constructivos acompañando mis votos negativo y de cierre.

Comment: También estoy parcialmente de acuerdo. Así como un programador no debe abandonar su código si este no funciona a la primera, este debe ser capaz de tolerar los votos negativos. En relación a los comentarios, mostrar en ellos paciencia, amabilidad pero sobre todo disposición orientar seguramente los animará a volver a participar y a hacerlo de la misma forma, con paciencia, amabilidad y disposición a ayudar.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, da la percepción que más que querramos apoyarnos como comunidad, tratamos de imponer. Es responsabilidad de todos nosotros el permitir nuevos conocimientos y apoyarnos en construir un camino para avanzar y no derribar a quien recien comienza a caminar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

La forma adecuada de moderar una comunidad pequeña no es la misma que la de moderar una comunidad grande. En las comunidades grandes el tratamiento que reciben los usuarios nuevos es más impersonal: esto es así porque simplemente hay demasiados usuarios nuevos como para poder hacerlo de otra forma. En Stack Overflow, por ejemplo, la cantidad de preguntas nuevas es tan abrumadora que casi nunca puedes tomarte tiempo con una pregunta, al menos que quieras gastar todo tu tiempo en eso.

Como muchos usuarios aquí son veteranos de Stack Overflow, tienden a hacer lo mismo que hacen allí.

En mi opinión, creo que sería mejor una actitud más pausada al tratar con nuevos usuarios. No hace falta ningún cambio de normas, simplemente un pequeño cambio de actitud: en vez de votar negativo o reportar inmediatamente, podríamos intentar dejar un comentario. Si al día siguiente no se ha arreglado el problema entonces ponemos el negativo o reportamos.

Comment: Opino que esta es la mejor solución!

Comment: Coincido con @rnrneverdies: convendría explicar a los usuarios nuevos qué están haciendo mal antes (o además de) freírles a negativos.

Comment: @Pablo  Me parece la idea mas acertada, no ser chocantes con los comentarios y aportar en lo que se pueda a mejorar la consulta de los mas nuevos.

Answer (score 14):

En el sitio en inglés tienden a ser muy estrictos, en mi caso, tiene pocos meses que me integré a la comunidad en inglés y llegué en ese lapso al top 10% con mi respectivo acceso a stack overflow careers ( yupi! ) y a participar en más de 5 comunidades, lo que hizo la diferencia fue la forma en que me recibieron, por lo cual les propongo los siguientes consejos:

- Siempre dar la bienvenida a los nuevos usuarios que hacen su primer pregunta.
- Si ven que le dan la bienvenida a alguien que preguntó traten de no ser demasiado duros.
- Si su pregunta puede mejorarse, mejórenla, los novatos son una oportunidad de ganar puntos fáciles, por lo que deberían de ser apreciados, en vez de humillados.
- Lo normal es que la mayoría no conozca como funciona el sitio, y hagan preguntas fuera de lugar, no se exasperen, aprovechen para convertir una pregunta fuera de lugar en un wiki o agregarla a uno ya existente, para que la gente sepa como funciona. Por ejemplo en el sitio en inglés me encontré a alguien con reputación 1 que preguntaba si podía contratar a alguien de ese sitio para que le resolviera un problema de php, y en menos de 5 minutos se llenó de votos negativos sin ninguna explicación. Le respondí a su pregunta sobre el sistema de reputación, sobre la consulta de los top respondedores de etiquetas y sobre el sitio de empleos de stack overflow, mi respuesta recibió votos positivos de quienes no lo sabían y se previno la eliminación quedando todoss satisfechos.
- Finalmente, un principio ético que sugiero es la regla de oro, trata como te gustaría ser tratado. Pienso que la manera de moderar una counidad pequeña y una grande es la misma, con mucha empatía y respeto a las diferencias.

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo con tu postura. Me pasó en SuperUser que me bombardearon con votos negativos porque no me podía dar a entender, debido a mi bajo nivel de inglés. Por lo general trato de investigar y revisar todo lo que tengo a la mano antes de preguntar y me sugerían que mejorara lo que pregunto pero no **en qué forma** debía mejorarlo. (Cont.)...

Comment: ... (Cont.) Llegué a abrir un Meta para poder averiguar qué hacer. Aún más, pasó tiempo y nadie respondió lo que pregunté, así que de seguir investigando encontré UNA solución, la cuál también fue votada negativa... llegando a comentar que era una solución **errónea**... o sea, ni tratar de solucionar pero si votar negativamente mi solución, que aunque quizás no haya sido la mejor, sirvió para lo que, al menos yo la necesité... quizás le servía a alguien más... o no.

Answer (score 4):

Bueno, Hoy tuve feedback de 2 personas, uno es un amigo y otro es empleado de una compañia.

Ambos me dijeron que les da pereza usar el sitio porque ponen muchos problemas por las preguntas. Se quejan de que les han cerrado o ignorado preguntas por ser muy amplias o porque carecen de sentido, así que en vez de enredarse se han ido a otros foros o a facebook.

SI a FACEBOOK!!
por ejemplo el grupo de programadores C# tiene 29.000 miembros y lo usan para todo, y mucho para preguntas y respuestas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que debemos entender que los usuarios llegan SO en busca de ayuda, y al menos el feedback que me dieron demuestra que los estamos espantando porque les estamos creando otro problema.

A mi modo de verlo **hay mucha fricción en el proceso de evaluación de las preguntas,** es decir comparemos **que le piden a alguien para hacer una pregunta en facebook** - o lo que sea- **NADA**.

En este momento debemos preocuparnos mucho por reducir esa fricción y porque en esencia la mayoría de los usuarios que llegarán **comenzarán desde 0 en SO**.

Muchas reglas pueden ser perfectamente válidas para alguien con más experiencia en SO pero para alguien nuevo se convierten en fricción, y pueden levar a: porque hacer mis preguntas o aportes allí si en otros lados los puedo hacer si problema.

No se si sea algo generalizado, pero **debemos bajar el tono en la forma en cómo se juzga / trata a un usuario**, especialmente a usuarios nuevos y tomar una actitud mucho más constructiva pues a la final **son como niños**, debemos guiarlos y mostrarles la manera correcta de hacer las cosas, en lugar de **juzgarlos como 'adultos' desde el comienzo**.

Comment: En la beta privada, se supone que hay que llenar el sitio con preguntas y respuestas del tipo que queremos ver. ¿En serio queremos que eso de la imagen se convierta en el modelo de futuras preguntas y respuestas?

Answer (score 4):

Disculpen si hago catarsis con respecto a este tema pero me siento identificado. 
El otro día comente esto a mis compañeros y lo exprese como *"bulling en conocimiento"* con respecto a la inflexibilidad que denote.

Desde que entre a esta comunidad me vi abrumado por el *elitismo* que imponen. Admito que muchos de los usuarios de este sitio son profesionales en la materia y que están por muy por encima del nivel de otro sitios con el mismo propósito y eso me hace querer formar parte de este grupo pero hay que saber entender que todo el que entra acá no es un usuario experimentado como en enSO. Se olvidaron de sus raíces. SO no nació con 10m de usuarios experimentados.

Yo vengo de otras comunidades donde hay cierta flexibilidad a la hora de formular las preguntas y donde se entiende que, el que esta al otro lado del monitor, no tiene las mismas capacidades para expresar sus problemas técnicos por falta de conocimientos en uno o diversos temas. Hay veces que, cuando se responde una pregunta, el mismo moderador lee la pregunta para corregirla y darle claridad a la misma.

Como cualquier sitio que empieza de cero necesita ganarse su audiencia y educarla para que genere contenido de calidad. Imponer reglas, normas y actitudes estrictas dejan en muy claro el objetivo del sitio y dejan de lado a personas que no pueden cumplir esos estándares.

Admito que mi respuesta es subjetiva pero lo veo necesario para que se entienda que necesaria mas empatía con el otro que es nuevo.