# Propuesta de edición de preguntas pobres

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Por el perfil de los usuarios novatos en SO Español, nos encontramos frecuentemente con casos en que alguien llega y plantea su primera pregunta tan mal que en minutos es cerrada.

El usuario sólo recibe un link a "cómo editar tu pregunta". Y cada día tengo más convicción de que ese link no lo ayuda.

Creo que este sitio está todavía en su infancia, y necesitamos más tiraje. Esto se puede obtener, a mi juicio, de varias maneras.

1. Para los que participamos en SO inglés, cuando una pregunta esté redactada por un hispano y sea cerrada o votada en contra por su inglés chapucero, proponerle plantearla en SO español.
2. Para los que publican en SO español y de verdad no se entiende lo que pregunta, usar los comentarios para averiguar un poco más sobre la duda del usuario y si es necesario proponerle una redacción a la pregunta.

Este segundo punto me parece importante. En vez de mandarlo a leer un link y cerrarle la pregunta, se puede dejar en espera y ayudarlo a re-redactarla.

Hasta el día en que nos sobren preguntas, hay que cuidar las que recibimos. Hoy en día **pueden pasar dos horas sin preguntas nuevas** y no nos podemos dar el lujo de botar las que no satisfagan el estándar. En otras palabras, hasta que tengamos el tiraje de SO en inglés, tenemos que ser un sitio más didáctico con nuestro público objetivo.

Ejemplo de una pregunta que re-redacté a punta de interrogar al usuario en los comentarios: [Cargando la web de forma asíncrona pero sin url](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55561/cargando-la-web-de-forma-as%C3%ADncrona-pero-sin-url)

**Es más**, creo que desde hoy voy a dedicar algunos minutos cada día a revisar preguntas cerradas, evaluar si se cerraron por mala redacción, hablar con el OP, mejorarlas y proponerlas para reapertura. Seguro hay una pila de preguntas en esa condición.

**EDIT:** además, aunque una pregunta no esté mal redactada, siempre es bueno ayudar indentando correctamente el código y sobretodo **añadiendo tags**. He visto muchas preguntas de `datatables` sin el tag `jquery`, y muchas con el tag `django` sin el tag `python`

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/194/como-trataremos-a-los-usuarios-nuevos-primera-pregunta

Comment: Buena iniciativa, felicidades. Y hago algunos comentarios. No creo que el sitio esté en la infancia, ya tenemos más de 470 días en beta. Tampoco estoy convencido que nos falten preguntas; según las métricas del área 51, un sitio con 10 preguntas al día está Ok, aquí se hacen 90. Necesitamos, eso si, contestar más preguntas y me parece que esta propuesta contribuye __en gran medida__ a ese logro, las buenas preguntas atraen más y mejores respuestas. No parece que el problema del sitio se el _engagement_.

Comment: *Y cada día tengo más convicción de que ese link no lo ayuda.*: Creo que el problema no es el contenido del enlace, sino que varios usuarios no lo leen.

Comment: Eso es porque se ponen a la defensiva

Comment: **Punto 1** Perfecto, pero ¿cómo identificar a un usuario que habla español en SO? Pregunto porque realmente no se me ocurre.. **Punto 2**  Estoy más cerca de las opiniones de toledano y sstan, aunque sí creo que ese enlace no es tan útil como podría serlo; pero antes de recomendar un trabajo manual sobre cada una de las preguntas (un trabajo casi *asistencialista*), ¿no crees que se debería proponer una mejora en el texto de ese enlace como primera instancia?

Comment: De acuerdo con amenadiel. Gracias por la iniciativa.

Answer (score 1):

el tenernos un poco mas de respeto y tomar en cuenta nos guste o no las opiniones de los demás ayudara a crecer este sitio, personalmente siempre me han ayudado pero me ha sorprendido la forma en que algunos se tratan, es precisamente una de las razones por las que me salí de los foros de MSDN, por los insultos que entre colaboradores se manejaban, solo quiero pedir como un usuario que a lo mejor no pinta nada en este sitio, que se tomen en cuenta las opiniones constructivas

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo en que se puede orientar mejor a los nuevos usuarios respecto a cómo usar este sitio.

En tu pregunta has dicho lo que se debería hacer:

- Editar la pregunta para mejorar las posibilidades de que otros miembros de la comunidad puedan ayudar.
- En los comentarios, comunicarse con el OP para que edite su pregunta; explicando mejor qué es lo que está preguntando.

Acerca del punto #1, lo que he hecho es comentar lo siguiente:

> [Welcome to Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). please **translate your question
>   to spanish**.

Respecto al punto #2, mis comentarios son así:

> Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido
>   del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
>   **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor
>   revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el
>   código o lo que coloques en tu
>   pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee:
>   **[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Con esto, cada usuario tiene la información para mejorar su propia pregunta / respuesta.

---

Sin embargo, esto no es así con todos los nuevos usuarios; en mi opinión, la gran mayoría no leen los comentarios y cuando responden, lo hacen a las respuestas dadas (ejemplo: *omiten estos tips del sitio*).

Creo que *tomando como ejemplo los comentarios que he colocado arriba*, éstos deberían ser menos "informales", pero ser mas (directos).

**tl; dr:** No creo que exista una fórmula mágica que les llegue a todos los usuarios, pero, la colaboración que cada miembro de la comunidad pueda aportar será muy importante para el sitio, el cual es de todos y para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Totalmente de acuerdo. 
Noté que hay muchos puristas por acá y la verdad es que solo alejan a las personas que quieren ayudar.
En mi caso, no pasó ni un minuto cuando un usuario me "invito" a ver las reglas de respuesta solo porque pedí más datos para ayudar en mi respuesta. 
Yo se que no tengo aun los puntos necesarios para dejar comentarios, pero caray! 
Quiero apoyar a los desarrolladores inexpertos. 
En fin, ojala se pueda convertir en una comunidad cooperativa y menos "purista".
Saludos

Comment: Paciencia, Litta, juntar 50 puntos es cosa de pocas horas, y entonces podrás usar los comentarios para pedir clarificaciones.

Comment: @Litta no creo que deberias tomarte tan personal el que alguien te muestre las reglas del sitio, porque para algo estan creo que es necesario una buena otrografia, gramatica y un punto claro en todas las preguntas y respuestas. saludos

Comment: @David no, para nada me lo tomo personal. Solo no me gusta que algunos crean que el sitio es solo para mantener un cierto status y con esto ahuyentan a las personas que quieren contribuir (Estas personas solo buscan "famita", no contribuyen). Es una realidad que la comunidad hispana necesita más material que pueda ser comprensible en su idioma, pero para esto necesitamos más contribución.

Comment: @LittaHervi creo que has dado sin quererlo en el clavo, las personas en la versión en inglés ubicadas en el top 10% ganan si no mal recuerdo estadísticamente perciben cerca del doble de salario en comparación con programadores promedio, y los que están en el top 1% de reputación cerca del 300% más. Participar en este sitio ayuda mucho a tu status y nivel de vida directa o indirectamente, así que no está mal que se lo tomen demasiado en serio siempre y cuando no lastimen a los demás.