# Premiar a los nuevos usuarios que elaboren una buena pregunta

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Hace unos minuto observe una pregunta , en la cual me gusto el comportamiento de la comunidad.

> [Sucesion malabarista en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218100/sucesion-malabarista-en-python)

Considero que deberiamos tener mas acciones como estas para los nuevos usuarios , y evitar cometer los errores de Stackoverflow en ingles

> [¿Como trataremos a los usuarios nuevos, primera pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/194/como-trataremos-a-los-usuarios-nuevos-primera-pregunta)

La idea es ver personas nuevas en el chat compartir , de eso trata estar en una comunidad, siempre y cuando exista el respeto (Cosa que hasta el momento se mantiene y felicito a cada miembro activo en el Chat).

Por momentos para algunos usuarios es dificil elaborar una buena pregunta , y se que [la comunidad esta trabajando para mejorar esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3749/queremos-banners-de-ayuda-para-usuarios), sabemos que los votos dependen de cada persona , estado de animo, comportamiento, entre otros.

Por tal motivo quisiera que acciones como estas sean premiadas para otros usuarios nuevo  y asi ampliar nuestra comunidad , pero como somos comunidad y debemos estar de acuerdo vine a hacer mi respectiva pregunta:

> ¿Seria correcto premiar a los nuevos usuarios que elaboren una buena
> Pregunta ?

Asi mismo, he visto muchos usuarios con puntuacion menores a 1000 realizando ediciones pequeñas que antes las rechazaba, pero ahora veo el esfuerzo que estan colocando su granito de arena para que el sitio se mantenga con su traje de gala, por tal motivo mi modo estricto de aceptar una pregunta editada ha bajado un poco

Comment: Por ahi se podrian destacar de alguna forma?

Comment: Está la cola de revisión para primeras publicaciones, no es que sea especial, pero podría servir para encontrar esos nuevos usuarios.

Comment: Considero que el mejor premio para un usuario nuevo, y todos los demás, es que la pregunta reciba excelentes respuestas y qué mejor que recibir una respuesta enriquecida con aportes de la comunidad.

Comment: en parte tienes razon @Rubén, pero no todo el tiempo actuamos de esa forma, si pregunta un usuario con puntuacion superior a 100 por ejemplo, somos mas flexibles para darle su +1 o -1 (me incluyo) ; por otro lado si aplicamos tu logica el usuario que elaboro una buena pregunta ve como se llenan las respuestas que le dieron de +1 mientras que su pregunta es 0;

Comment: Entiendo ahora que lo que estás proponiendo es que votemos positivamente las buenas preguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que sería injusto para aquellos que alguna vez fueron nuevos usuarios e hicieron buenas preguntas. Estos usuarios en aquel momento no fueron premiados.

También un usuario experimentado podría crear un usuario nuevo y hacer una buena pregunta porque con el usuario *no nuevo* no recibe el premio, entonces de esta manera recibiría el premio.

En caso de implementarse, habría que plantearse si está bien o mal, usar alguna herramienta que confirme si realmente es un nuevo usuario o uno antiguo.

Tampoco sabemos qué tipo de premio es, quizás más reputación, alguna medalla, o poner la pregunta como si fuera una recompensa y que sea destacada por 7 días.